# PHP Memcached set always returns false

Tags: php, memcached

Here is the status of my memcached php extension on my Godaddy server;

[image]

And memcached seems to be running properly on the server, it is present in the ps -aux list;

[image]

I'm using this PHP script to test memcached;

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

ini_set('display_errors', true);

$mem = new memcached();

$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);

$result = $mem->get("Test");

if ($result) {

echo $result;

} else {

echo "Test key not found, adding key";

$mem->set("Test", "I found a match, memcache is working") or die("Nothing Saved...");

}
```

I have no idea whether I'm doing something wrong or not, but memcached seems to be unable to set anything.

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the very port memcached daemon listens to?

Comment: Ah, that's it. I am not very smart! The process runs on port 3452. I need to pay more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ps -aux shows memcache is on port 3452. Try changing:

```
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
```

to:

```
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 3452);
```